# PHP - if a value exists in an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array of objects called $filtes which goes as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Type
            [alias] => type
            [id] => 14
            [parent_id] => 9
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => car
                            [alias] => car
                            [id] => 15
                            [parent_id] => 14
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Model
            [alias] => model
            [id] => 18
            [parent_id] => 9
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => XF
                            [alias] => xf
                            [id] => 19
                            [parent_id] => 18
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => XJ
                            [alias] => xj
                            [id] => 20
                            [parent_id] => 18
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => XK
                            [alias] => xk
                            [id] => 21
                            [parent_id] => 18
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => F-TYPE
                            [alias] => f-type
                            [id] => 22
                            [parent_id] => 18
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Condition
            [alias] => condition
            [id] => 24
            [parent_id] => 9
            [subs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [title] => new
                            [alias] => new
                            [id] => 24
                            [parent_id] => 9
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

What is the best practice to check if a word exists in $filters[$i]->title and $filters[$i]->subs[$j]->title. Speed is really important in this checking.

Comment: http://us1.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a simple recursive function:

```
function myArrayContainsWord(array $myArray, $word) {
    foreach ($myArray as $element) {
        if ($element->title == $word || 
            (!empty($myArray['subs']) && myArrayContainsWord($myArray['subs'], $word)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
if (myArrayContainsWord($filtes, $title)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you please take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322404/php-check-if-objects-exists), I'm kinda lost - Thanks

Comment: If you want to look for an ID instead of the title, you only have to change `$element->title` to `$element->id`

Answer (score 2):

I just upgraded the version of @zander-rootman, i added a field name option.

```
<?php
     function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack, $field) {
          foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
                $current_key=$key;
                if($needle==$value->$field() OR (is_array($value->$field() ) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value->$field(),$field ) != false)) {
                      return true;
                }
          }
          return false;
      }

     // Example of use
     $result = recursive_array_search('2', $ressourceInfo->packs(), "idSubscription");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP in_array and/or PHP array_key_exists ... You're using a multi dimensional array however, so I'm not sure how extensively you want to search.

```
 <?php
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
       $current_key=$key;
       if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Found this function in the PHP docs: http://www.php.net/array_search